# align reyclerview elements android

Tags: java, android

I have a recyclerview with a TextView and an EditText building the rows with the TextView on the left and the EditText right of it.
Currently view looks as follows:

```
Aaa:  value1
Abbsbc:  value2
Cskhkdhd: value3
HJhk:  value4
```

I would like the view to look this way:

```
            Aaa:  value1
     Abbsbc:  value2
 Cskhkdhd:  value3
         HJhk:  value4
```

the layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/brand_row"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/brand_selector">

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/divider"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/object"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_box_height"
    android:layout_below="@id/divider"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/noData"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_box_height"
    android:layout_below="@id/divider"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/object"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:hint="Enter value"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/divider"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try adding the the object text views to a different layout with a gravity righty for example?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in Textview:

```
android:textAlignment="viewEnd" 
android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
```

Also I think this will still lead to uneven alignment if the length of textview text varies in rows, So its better if you use Linear Layout as parent layout. I have redone the xml accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/brand_row"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/brand_selector">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/object"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_box_height"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/noData"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_box_height"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/object"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Enter value"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/divider"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try LinearLayout with weight:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/brand_row"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/brand_selector">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/divider"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/object"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_box_height"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/noData"
            android:gravity="end"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_box_height"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Enter value"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/divider"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:   I added a gravity END to align on the right on the textView and a Startpadding on the EditText to leave space between label and value

Comment: none of the suggested answers has achieved the expected result.

Comment: I just edited my answer to align on the right, try it this way

Comment: oups, had double gravity attribute, now it should be ok: